# How to call API from each of the element rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I wonder if calling API for every element rendering is possible. The code below didn't work for me.

```
export default function App() {
  const items = [
    { title: 1, description: "description1" },
    { title: 2, description: "description2" }
  ];

  const finalTitleByApi = async (title) => {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${title}`
    ).then((response) => response.json());

    return response;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {items.map((item) => {
        return (
          <p>
            {finalTitleByApi(item.title).title}
          </p>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

What is wrong with the code above? Any help is will be appreciated.

This is the example codesandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/for-each-rendered-element-that-calls-api-pmcnn6?file=/src/App.js:879-886

Comment: since finalTitleByApi is an async function, finalTitleByApi() returns a promise

Comment: thank you @richardnelson do you have idea how it is done?

Comment: I have add solution with seperated answer, you can check it @AljohnYamaro

Comment: Was it helpful? [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/for-each-rendered-element-that-calls-api-forked-thxd1h?file=/src/index.js)  ? @AljohnYamaro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use **react-async** library , `hope will be helpful` [react-async](https://github.com/async-library/react-async)

Answer (score 0):

To trigger the async function use `useEffect` to invoke it during initial rendering of the component as follows. Additionally, you can use a state to manage it as well.

```
  const [responseState, setResponseState] = useState(null);

  const finalTitleByApi = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
    ).then((response) => response.json());

    console.log("Response: ", response);

    setResponseState(response);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    finalTitleByApi();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Response State: ", responseState);
  }, [responseState]);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply @Kavindu, however, what I am looking is for each of render of <p> it will call an api. I updated some things above to make it more clear. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I think is

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

import {useApplicationContext} from './Context';
export default function App() {
  const {titles, setTitles} = useApplicationContext();
  const items = [
    { title: "1", description: "description1" },
    { title: "5", description: "description2" },
    { title: "8", description: "description2" },
    { title: "9", description: "description2" },
    { title: "10", description: "description2" },
    { title: "24", description: "description2" }
  ];

  
  const makeDivs = () => {
    let a = {};
    items.map(async (item) => {
      const res = await fetch(
        `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${item.title}`
      ).then(response => response.json());
      a[item.title] = res.title;
      setTitles((prevState) => {
        return {...a}
      });
    })
  }

  React.useEffect(()=> {
    makeDivs()
  }, [])

  
  // console.log(a )
  return (
    <div>
      {JSON.stringify(titles)}
      {items.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <p
            key={Math.random()}
            style={{
              color: "black",
              backgroundColor: "yellow",
              height: 400,
              width: 400
            }}
          >
             <span>index: {item.title} {titles && titles[item.title]}</span>
          </p>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**used Context provider for not re-render component state**
link of sandbox is [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/for-each-rendered-element-that-calls-api-forked-thxd1h?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: Was it helpful ? @Kavindu Vindika

Comment: thank you @Hakob Sargsyan, this really works. I wonder if this will applied to nextjs?

Comment: @AljohnYamaro Of course it will applied on next.js , try to check [NextJs](https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjsmultipleasynccalls-olj035?fbclid=IwAR2fqlEJNNrApuv2dWNnPJi8iNmNfgWUNDxuMkby9e5gsP0-M6LV2XX_Cp4)

Comment: ow, as I check it again thoroughly, what you did is, you do all requests using useEffect, but I wonder if without it, like the other way, we call api inside paragraph tag. @Hakob Sargsyan

Comment: Yep , makeDivs function called from useEffect , makeDivs is doing api calls inside of async loop, for every item, state titles is a object(collection of titles , keys of object are api title id's for have a unique keys inside of object) , on every iteration I am doing update of state with clone of new object that I define in the Top , in the JSX we have a iteration over the items object that you define static in the component , and we are doing comparation - get from state titles identical title by static title id. @AljohnYamaro

Comment: why you want to call it inside of paragraph directly ? what will be give it you ? @AljohnYamaro

Comment: Maybe you want something like this [async-components](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/using-the-react-async-library-for-declarative-data-fetching)   , package for React - [React-async-library](https://github.com/async-library/react-async)

Comment: I already used that approach calling the api from useEffect @Hakob Sargsyan. I'm in the flow of calling the api inside an element, if the library(React-async-libray) you suggested fits (will try it later) . And I will tell you to post it as an answer and I will mark it the answer.

Comment: the react-async library is the answer, kindly make it as a post, and I will mark it as the answer. Thanks a lot. I highly appreciate your help.